# Order a dataframe primarily by the count of times a value appears in a column and secondarily by a second column

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the dataframe below which I would like to order primarily numerically by the count of times a value appears in the first column (bigger values first) and secondarily alphabetically(A-Z) based on the second column.

```
Name<-c("jack","jack","bob","david","mary")
Surname<-c("arf","dfg","hjk","dfgg","bn")
n1<-data.frame(Name, Surname)
```

It should be something like:

```
n1<-n1[
  order( n1[,1], n1[,2] ),
  ]
```

but I do not know how to order numerically based on count of values.

Comment: So is `n1[order( n1[,1], n1[,2] ),]` your expected output? If so, since you want to *"order primarily numerically by the count of times a value appears in the first column"* why do the `"jack"` entries not appear at the top?

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen a similar question in the past, particularly the order by counts bit, but something like `n1[order(tabulate(n1$Name)[n1$Name], n1$Surname),]` should do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036182/sort-a-dataframe-column-by-the-frequency-of-occurrence/35036797 and similar stuff here too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334709/sort-by-occurance-or-freq-in-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @thelatemail, you can do this in base R using:

```
n1[order(-table(n1$Name)[n1$Name], n1$Surname), ]
```

To sort by surname first, swap the arguments to `order()` around.

Comment: Be careful that since you're indexing by names of a table that if `n1$Name` is numeric, you could get the wrong result. Compare `x <- c(1,2,4,4)` and `table(x)[x]` vs `tabulate(x)[x]`, or even `table(x)[as.character(x)]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sqldf` likes the following:

```
library(sqldf)

n2 <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM 
             n1 JOIN (SELECT Name, COUNT(*) as C FROM n1 GROUP BY Name) as T 
             on n1.Name = T.Name 
             ORDER BY C DESC, Surname')
```

First grouped the names and then sort based on the count in decent order and `Surname` alphabetically.

Comment: Very useful. In the code chunk above what would I change if I want to sort primarily alphabetically the the second column?

Comment: Indeed You should change the second part of `ORDER BY`. I mean you change the `Surname` in `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
n1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(Name) %>%
  right_join(n1, by = "Name") %>% # join the count back to your original frame
  arrange(desc(n), Surname) %>% # order by highest count first, then Surname
  select(-n) # just return the original frame, with the sorting you asked for
```

Comment: FYI `count` is a shorthand for `group_by` plus `tally` plus `ungroup`

Comment: @camille Thx! I edited my answer to reflect your comment.